# Reading child tags via readXML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net

```
Dataset ds=new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("path of the xml");
```

However ds has multiple tables, I would like to fetch out the details tag information of Header and Footer separately:

```
XElement xElement = XElement.Parse(ds.GetXml().ToString());
  var items =xElement
                  .Descendants("Header");
```

Above code doesn't yield me the results, it comes back as empty.

How can i get Name & Number tag of Details tag per Header and per Footer? Can i create 2 datasets using ds.ReadXML separtely?

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Mapping>
 <Header>
   <Row>
      <Details>
      <Name>Name</Name> 
         <DataType>string</DataType>
         <Value>Mark</Value>
      </Details>
      <Details>
      <Name>Number</Name> 
         <DataType>int</DataType>
         <Value>1</Value>
      </Details>
   </Row>    
 </Header>
<Footer>
   <Row>
      <Details>
      <Name>Name</Name> 
         <DataType>string</DataType>
         <Value>John</Value>
      </Details>
      <Details>
      <Name>Number</Name> 
         <DataType>int</DataType>
         <Value>2</Value>
      </Details>
   </Row>
</Footer>
</Mapping>
```

Dataset 1 : Header info - So that i can loop thro' the rows

Dataset 2 : Footer info - So that i can loop thro' the rows

Or is there any other approach to fetch out name, number separately? the objective here is to fetch out the data and build a C# class like

```
public class Header
{
 public Header(){}

 public string Name;
 public int Number

}


public class Footer
{
 public Footer(){}

 public string Name;
 public int Number

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XElement mapping = XElement.Parse(ds.GetXml().ToString());
var query = from d in mapping.Descendants("Details")
            select new {
                Name = (string)d.Element("Name"),
                Number = (int)d.Element("Number")
            };
```

If you want to build your class instances:

```
var headers = from d in mapping.Element("Header")
                               .Element("Row").Elements("Details")
              select new Header {
                  Name = (string)d.Element("Name"),
                  Number = (int)d.Element("Number")
              };
```

Getting footers is same, except you should select `"Footer"` element first.

---

Also you can use XPath for selecting elements:

```
var headers = from d in mapping.XPathSelectElements("Header/Row/Details")
              select new Header {
                  Name = (string)d.Element("Name"),
                  Number = (int)d.Element("Number")
              };
```

Comment: Thanks, How can i make that select new Header - the Header class to be created dynamically, i want to create Header.cs with string Name and int Number - the XML file can contain any tags, those tags need to be part of the class?

Comment: @Sharpeye500 can you please clarify what 'xml can contain any tags' means? Some sample maybe

Comment: I want to create attribute names of the class based on the tags insied the xml, for ex, i want to dynamically create class header with tags name, number as public string name, public int number etc.. reading the tag and create classes. I want to create run time classes.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 and how you are going to use them if you don't know properties at compile time?

Comment: lazyberezovsky  - thats an excellent question, i missed to include the datatype in the xml. I have edited my question, please share your valuable thoughts.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 question is still here. E.g. you have some xml. You create object of unknown type with unknown properties (you don't now what data will be in xml). How you are going to use this unknown object in your code? You even don't know if it has `Name` property or not.

Comment: Thanks, <Name>Name</Name> , <DataType>string</DataType> by reading the <Name> tag, i need to create an attributed named Name, by reading the datatype tag, i create its data type and by <value> tag, the value needs to be set to that created attribute.